# Resizing object called from using string containing JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am trying to use JavaScript to pick a random row from a table in a Google Sheet, then display it on an HTML page.

So far I have managed to get the random row to display as an object, but I can't figure out how to resize that object.

Here is my script:

```js
< script >
  window.onload = function() {
    var albumno = Math.random() * 400;
    var albumno = Math.round(albumno);
    var albumurl = "https://docs.google.com/SHEET-ID" + albumno + "SHEET-GID";

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = albumno;
    document.getElementById("albumpath").innerHTML = "<object data='" + albumurl + "'>";
  }; <
/script>
```

And currently I'm inserting it within the body as follows:

```html
<section id="features">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>

    <p id="output"></p>

    <object width="1000" height="200" id="albumpath"></object>

  </div>
</section>
```

How can I resize this object? Using the URL and variable, the google sheet URL generates a table similar to [this](https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20B%2C%20C%2C%20D%2C%20F%20WHERE%20C%20CONTAINS%20%27Florida%27%20&key=0AqAPbBT_k2VUdEtXYXdLdjM0TXY1YUVhMk9jeUQ0NkE). Courtesy of [this site](http://www.bohyunkim.net/blog/archives/2831).

Alternatively is there a way I could just pull the table right from Google Sheets HTML page, and then insert it into my HTML page? That is my ultimate plan, but I'm trying to start with inserting the table as an object. Helping pointing me in the right direction for this task would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit odd to be placing an object into another object tag. You could try using a `<div>` in your HTML and then adding height and width attributes to your `<object>` either when you create it in your JavaScript or afterwards. E.g.

```
document.getElementById("albumpath").innerHTML = '<object width="1000" height="200" data="' + albumurl + '">';
```

or

```
document.getElementById("albumpath").setAttribute("width", "1000");
```

Comment: It did feel incorrect to place the object into an object tag. I initially tried adding the height and width to the object, but it didn't work when I used it inside an object tag. So, how exactly do I insert my object "albumpath" using a div? This is my first time working with JS.

Comment: You could try replacing `<object width="1000" height="200" id="albumpath"></object>` with `<div id="albumpath"></div>` and then inserting your object with a width and height: `document.getElementById("albumpath").innerHTML = '<object width="1000" height="200" data="' + albumurl + '">';`.

Comment: Did this help? If so, please select the answer.